# OutputCache VaryByCustom : GetVaryByCustomString is not called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have defined `OutputCache` filter on my Action method as following

```
[OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "Culture", Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

And overrided `GetVaryByCustomString` method in **Global.asax** as following:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    return "test";
}
```

Exactly this code is working with template mvc application, so i assume syntax is just right.

Unfortunately not in my application.

ANY ideas from you guys who had the same problem what could cause it ?

I have really tried to figure out for HOURS but with no success.

Please write any suggestion on this that worked for you.

**UPDATE:** It's working only if controller class is derived directly from `Controller` class. If there's any other class between them it's not working. Any ideas what could be the cause ? There is a lot of common functionality in my derived  `DefaultController` class so it would be awkward to implement the same thing in every controller.

**UPDATE2:** if found out the problem is i'm overriding BeginExecuteCore on each controller and if I modify anything from Controller object (Cookies, Session) GetVaryByCustomString won't be called anymore. Anybody having idea why ?

Comment: What's the expected behavior? What's the current results?

Comment: Exptected behavior is that GetVaryByCustomString will be fired.

Current behavior is that it is not fired.

Comment: Is there anything related to OutputCaching in your Web.config?

Comment: not that i can recognize something related to it, but what part of web.config could be related ? than i can look into it.

Comment: `<outputCache>` section?

Comment: No, there is no `<outputCache>` section

Comment: If possible, could you post the code for your DefaultController class? that may prove helpful.

Comment: if found out the problem is i'm overriding BeginExecuteCore on each controller and if I modify anything from Controller object (Cookies, Session) GetVaryByCustomString won't be called anymore.

Anybody having idea why ?

Comment: Old thread but figured I'd add some notes here in case someone else also has the same problem. I have a custom Authorize attribute for my own membership and was setting SetNoServerCaching and SetNoStore on the Response cache so I nothing was getting cached and the even was never firing.